# Fast way of writing SQL server table into file

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a remote SQL server. I want to make a *local* copy of all tables in this server. I don't care about the file format used locally, I'm looking for the fastest approach of getting the data from SQL server into the file. *(note: server side backup is not an option)*

This is my current approach:

**Step 1**. Creating a reader and read all data into a List of objects

```
while (reader.Read()) {

    var fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        objects.Add(reader.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

**Step 2**. Convert the objects to strings

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
foreach (var o in objects) {
    test.Add(o.ToString());
}
```

**Step 3**. Write the string to a (CSV) file

```
foreach (var s in test) {
    backupFile.Write("\"");
    backupFile.Write(s);
    backupFile.Write("\";");
}
```

I've measured the performance of these 3 steps:

- Step 1 takes 3 seconds
- Step 2 takes **2.8 seconds**
- Step 3 takes 0.8 seconds

I'm looking for a way to speed up step 2. Is there a faster way of getting these objects to a file? (doesn't have to be a text file. Binary of local database file is also ok)

Comment: You could probably do those operations in a T-SQL Query so that it returns everything formatted in CSV instead of having to go through each record in C#.

Comment: Why not just loop through the data once, and do the string conversion and file writing as you read each row from your query?

Comment: My guess is that the fastest mechanism would be to use SQL Server's [bulk export functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx).  There is a bcp.exe utility that seems to do pretty much exactly what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice I'm pretty sure that method can only write to files that the Server has access to. Probably not available because of the same constraint that stops server side backups.

Comment: Have you looked at the [bcp (bulk copy) command-line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) provided by SQL Server? Should be fast, works on the command line for any query, spits out data into a file on disk ....

Comment: What about using SQL management Studio and generate scripts+data option?

Comment: Granted, the bulk export functionality of SQL Server may be limited to  only files that the server can access, but if performance is a critical concern, then I would try to implement a solution that first does a bulk export to a local file and then transfers that file to the remote machine. I assume that the performance concern here is to minimize the amount of time that the database is locked, not necessarily getting the data transferred over the network.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: I know that you are primarily asking about step 2, but I wanted to point out that you *might* be suffering from some (relatively significant?) performance penalties due to boxing value types when you call `reader.GetValue(i)`.

You *might* be able to reduce the overall execution time of steps 1 and 2 by using the more type-specific functions on the DataReader class, such as GetInt32, GetDecimal, GetDateTime, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Why are you bothering with three steps exactly.

Why not

```
while (reader.Read()) {

    var fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
           backupFile.Write("\"");
           backupFile.Write(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
           backupFile.Write("\";");;
    }
    backupFile.WriteLine();
 }
```

Unless of course you're using two threads. One that pushes the data into a collection. And one that flushes the data into a file.

Comment: I've splitted my code into steps to be able to measure the performance. The final result will indeed be one loop, but it won't be noticeable faster.

Comment: I see well I don't think you can improve `ToString()` but you might want to consider putting it on a separate thread so you can fetch from the database while writing out the file. (They are both IO bound operations instead of CPU bound)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about the file format used locally, how About loading your SQL table to a DataTable object and use:

```
datatable.WriteXml("c:\YourFile.xml");
```

Comment: that would likely be much slower

Comment: @Conrad. Correct. The loading into a DataTable is already way slower than the method I currently use

Comment: Not to mention it would load the entire table into memory - in my case that would be millions of rows. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use the OPENROWSET command. Example:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT Name, Date FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT [Name], GETDATE() FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This c:\testing.xls would sit on the server? I need it on the client. There is no way in my current solution that I can download this file from the client (automated)